# Identity Server 4 with Asp.net (.Net framework 4.7.2) How to fix "Invalid grant type for client"

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 with Asp.Net MVC (.net framework). When Authorize, my site can navigate to Identity Server but get error: Invalid grant type for client. How can I fix it? Give me an sample for this combination. Many thanks.

Identity Server client config

```
{
      "ClientId": "nfc",
      "ClientName": ".net framework client",

      // 5AF90EA2-CA6E-4AF9-AC1C-EAC72933D20D
      "ClientSecrets": [ { "Value": "bBsQFRHNGCMB6W3EdybGe/lO8iOawFpeQ2ipC+nhGVM=" } ],
      "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "client_credentials" ],
      "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile" ],
      "AllowOfflineAccess": true,

      "RedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:44398/signin-oidc" ],
      "FrontChannelLogoutUris": [ "http://localhost:44398/signout-oidc" ],
      "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:44398/signout-callback-oidc" ]
    },
```

Asp.net Client Startup.cs

```cs
[assembly: OwinStartup("ProductionConfiguration", typeof(NetFrameworkClient.Startup))]

namespace NetFrameworkClient
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "oidc",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:44398/signin-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:44398/signout-callback-oidc",
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                Scope = "openid profile",
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        var identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                        var name = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == identity.NameClaimType)?.Value;

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Authorize On Controller

```cs
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

The error I got: Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client
Invalid grant type for client

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because in your identity server config your client id is "nfc" whereas in your .NET Application's config you are specifying the client id as "mvc".

In order for your .net application to authorize with Identity Server it needs to pass back a VALID client ID.

You can find out more information in the docs: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works for you but for me: the MVC 4.7.2 has "GrantType": "hybrid"
so I change the setting in IdentityServer4 to "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "hybrid" ]